How to Synchronize HLS Video and Audio Streams in Flutter?
I'm developing a Flutter application where I need to play HLS video and audio streams from separate URLs and keep them synchronized. I'm looking for the best approach to ensure that both streams start and stay in sync during playback.
What are the best practices or recommended approaches for synchronizing HLS video and audio streams in Flutter? Are there specific packages, techniques, or methods that can help ensure both streams are fully loaded and synchronized during playback?
I have tried using better_player for video playback and just_audio for audio playback, but I'm facing synchronization issues, especially when the audio stream takes longer to load compared to the video stream.
